# Code for check particular app was installed or not

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app for iOS 6 with Facebook Share option. I need to check out that this app can able to check wether Facebook app was installed in device or not.

I have already tried with Account  Store. But it was not working. Is there any some other way for this issue. I need help with code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for it using `-[UIApplication canOpenURL:]`. The facebook custom URL scheme is "fb:".

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    // Facebook is installed
}
```

Comment: Can you please send me any sample facebook custom URL.

Comment: "fb://profile" is a facebook custom URL. Other examples are at http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook